# How to implement autoscroll to follow my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've looked at several tutorials online and a few similar questions on SO but not been able to work out how to make the screen autoscroll left and right so that my `#sheep` stays in the centre of the screen.

I'm using javascript and jquery to move a simple div across the screen.

Here's my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JosephByrne/CkkVr/

What's the best method of making the screen follow my div?

Comment: I just wanted to say that Dave is an excellent sheep. My cat is called Dave and is a similar shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to move the wrong element left/right. I think you need to leave your sheep in the middle of the screen then move the background.

Something like:

```
var walkLeft = function() {
    $('#background').animate({left:"-=10px",top:"-=2px"}, 100);
    $('#background').animate({left:"-=10px",top:"+=2px"}, 100);
};

var walkRight = function() {
    $('#background').animate({left:"+=10px",top:"-=2px"}, 100);
    $('#background').animate({left:"+=10px",top:"+=2px"}, 100);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CkkVr/22/ (you'll need to "jump right" to see the sheep), but you get the general idea!

Comment: I see what you mean, I can reengineer all the movement functions etc but the problem with your fiddle is that the background doesn't continue tiling indefinitely, it just stays the width of the page when its opened up. So you end up just getting more and more white space rather than a continuing background.

Comment: Yes it does, you just need to add a repeat-x to the background property on the div, that way you'll have a repeating background. Although you'll probably want to make the background width masssive and hide the overflow.

Comment: I already have a repeat-x on the background(see fiddle) though

Comment: Have you made the background div wide (e.g. 9999px, then turned of overflow on the body?)?

Comment: what do you mean by turn off overflow? Is that a CSS property? Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: No problem. You can turn off the horizontal scrollbar by adding a overflow-x: hidden to your CSS file on the body tag. Then you can change your background with to be 9000px (or bigger) wide. This will allow your background to scroll while moving the sheep. It's how a lot of the image carousels you see on the internet work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CkkVr/25/ <-- I've shown how I would do it here on the "walk" movements.

Answer (score 1):

You need something similar to this:

```
function scrollContainer() {
    var $sheep = $("#sheep");
    $("body").scrollLeft($sheep.position().left + $sheep.width());
}
```

That utilizes jQuery's [`scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) function as well as the [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) function (on the sheep).

---

You just need to keep messing with the math until it works out properly...

I've implemented it on the "jump" functions here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dxe8a/11/

```
function scrollContainer() {
    var $sheep = $("#sheep");
    var $body = $("body");
    var windowWidthOver2 = ($(window).width()/2);
    var pos = $sheep.position().left + windowWidthOver2 - $sheep.width() - 80;
    if($body.width() <= (pos + windowWidthOver2 - $sheep.width() - 80)) {
        $body.width($body.width() + windowWidthOver2);
    }
    $body.scrollLeft(pos);
}
```

You should alter it so that it looks a bit better, but at least it follows your sheep somewhat.

**P.S. it works better in fiddle if you view it in "/show": http://jsfiddle.net/Dxe8a/11/show**

Comment: i'm playing around with this to make it work but it doesn't look great because when it scrolls it snaps straight to it, rather than moving the view slowly (ie smoothly scrolling). Do you know if its possible to achieve this with your method?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. Just as you can animate the position of your sheep, you can animate the 'scrollLeft' property as well. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxe8a/12/show/ (source: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxe8a/12/)